# Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) when trying to implement abstractmethod

Tags: python, oop, abstract-methods

I am trying to implement a class with `@abstractmethod` decorator and subclasses. In the examples I have seen, the abstractmethod has always just the word `pass` in it for the abstract class. What I am trying to do however is having a abstractmethod that does in fact have functionality, but with several free variables which get assigned in the subclasses:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Animal(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name=''):

        self.name = name

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self, sound, move):
        print('open mouth and ' + sound)
        print('advance by ' + move)


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_something(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.do_something(self, sound='bark', move='moving legs')
```

If I apply this, I get:

```
MyDog = Dog('Charly')
MyDog.name
```

> 'Charly'

so far, so good.

```
MyDog.do_something()
```

> Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Surely, something is off with my understanding of abstract classes (doing it for the first time).
Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: try `return super().do_something(sound='bark', move='moving legs')`

Comment: RecursionError: something embarrassing like this, I thought... :)